# Hide rows if column contains particular text/ string

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, hide

I have a datagridview wich I have no bound datasource too I also have a button and three rows in my datagridview. If my column named STATUS contains the word CLOSED I would like to hide that entire row but i dont want to delete it just hide it.

If anyone woyuld like to know I am ussing VB.net

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a bound datasource you want to capture the `DataGridView.DataSourceChanged` event.

**Would look like this.**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataSourceChanged

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).Rows

        If row.Cells("status").Value.ToString.ToLower.Contains("Closed") Then

            row.Visible = False

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

If you are not using a datasource you would want to capture the `DataGridView.RowsAdded` event.

**Would look like this.**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded

    Dim dg As DataGridView = sender

    If dg.Columns.Count > 0 And e.RowIndex <> 0 Then

        Dim theRow As DataGridViewRow = dg.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        If theRow.Cells("status").Value.ToString.ToLower.Contains("closed") Then

            theRow.Visible = False

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How much would this slow down when looping 1000+ rows?.. Looking to implement something similar to this and looking for the best approach when there are a lot of rows to consider, might just 'Select' correct values prior to binding the datasource but that's more work, than just hiding the rows, in my code.

Comment: On a dataset i have which takes an average ~55 millseconds without any manipulation. (10k rows). Seems to take about ~10x as long when looping through the rows and filtering after the DataSourceChanged event. What i would do performance wise is filter my datatable that is my datasource dtb.DefaultView.RowFilter = "status like '%closed%'" which has significantly better performance. However the OP did not have a bound datasource so you really do not have an option besides looping through the rows and taking a hit on performance.